# How to change TreeViewItem background color according to property of bound data?

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a TreeView where the data is bound to generic derived wrapper classes over my data hierarchy.
My bound wrapper classes include added fields like "IsHilighted" and "IsExpanded".

I would like to change the background of any TreeViewItem according to its bound data property "IsHiglighted". I would like to set the color of Hilighted item to the same (or lighter) color as the default Selected item background color.

Ideally, I would like to not modify existing XAML... I mean being able to eventually add the behavior through code.

**UPDATE**

I have found a partial solution: I had to add triggers as defined below. Code included below.

```
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsHilighted}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SlateBlue"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="160"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

**Still not resolved**: How could I bind the color of Hilighted item (see partial solution above) to the "Selected" TreeViewItem background color, i.e. replace "SlateBlue" on partial solution to binding to existing selected item style background color ?

Original TreeView XAML code:

```
<TreeView Name="TreeViewSelectScopeStudy" MinHeight="24" Margin="7" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TvItemRootPssTreeViewRoot.ChildsView}" Height="Auto"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

    <TreeView.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}"/>
        </Style>


        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Green" />

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type scopeSelection:WrapperSimulatedInfoStudy}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Childs}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TvItemName}" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type scopeSelection:WrapperSimulatedInfoSimulation}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Item.InvalidityReason}">
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.IsValid}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="160"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Item.IsValid}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Item.InvalidityReason}"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsHilighted}"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TvItemName}" Margin="5,0,0,0" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Item.InvalidityReason}">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Item.IsValid}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define one more property called `IsItemSelected` and bind it to `TreeViewItem`s `IsSelected` property (similar to how you have done for `IsExpanded`).

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsItemSelected}"/>
</Style>
```

Then you could define a `DataTrigger` for the `IsItemSelected` property and set the background color.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsItemSelected}" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks Anand. I agree that it should works properly. But my biggest problem is to find the way to bind to the existing color of the "selected item style". I wonder if I have to define a new style based on the "selected style" of the TreeViewItemStyle or another way ? And how to do it. I'm currently trying to do it by code but I have some difficulties.